# Image is not loading on the html page

Tags: html, spring-boot

I use Spring Boot and try to load image to my html page.

Full path to the file : file:///D:/DYPLOM%20PROJECT/src/main/resources/static/slov.png
When I run in the browser full path, everything in working and image is uploading.

I tried different variants but have the same issue - image is not loading in my html page
———————————————————————-
[image]

It is my `welcomePage` where I need to load image
[image]

Image `slov.png` stores in the /resources/static, you can see it :
[image]

And when I go to localhost - welcomePage , I have it :

[image]

Console errors :

[image]

[image]

This errors with the path `<img src="../../resources/static/slov.png">`

Comment: Could you show us some code please? Otherwise it is hard to figure out what the problem is

Comment: @GillesHeinesch I added details, if you need something else - tell

Comment: Thanks! Where do you define that server can access the static folder?

Comment: @GillesHeinesch I didn't define it

Comment: Can you add the console error to your question please

Comment: @GillesHeinesch I added console errors to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230730/discussion-between-gilles-heinesch-and-jack).

Answer (score 1):

You need to write like this.
`<img src="../static/slov.png">`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rewriting the `img` tag like so:

```
<img src="../static/slov.png">
```

This will locate the resource correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<img src="static/slov.png">`

Comment: It doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're requesting a location of the image which doesn't exist.

Try changing your `img` tag to the following:

```
<img src="../../resources/static/slov.png">
```

With this edit, you should get your image now.

Comment: It doesn't help

Comment: I've done changes to my post @Jack If it still doesn't work can you tell me the file location of the file which requests the file

Comment: It is still doesn't work
`welcomePage` - html file that stores in the resources in the directory `templates`

So, full path to my image : `codeD:\DYPLOM PROJECT\src\main\resources\static`

And full path to my html file where I need to show image : `D:\DYPLOM PROJECT\src\main\resources\templates`

Comment: Thanks! And the other buttons work where you render the other html files?

Comment: I've just changed the img location once again, can you try this solution too please @Jack